# Extract name of a file without its extension using php

Tags: php, mysql

I upload a file say 'example.csv'...How do I store 'example' inside a variable using php so as to create a table in the database having the table name as 'example'?

Comment: You can use both `pathinfo()` and `basename()` PHP functions for that.

Comment: The form that uploads a file to the database is of enctype=multipart/form-data. Hence i am getting an encoded filename. How to resolve this issue in order to get the filename without the extension? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: @TanayPardeshi I post an answer below, you can very easily get this filename without the extension.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use `pathinfo()`:

http://php.net/pathinfo

```
$filename = "example.csv";
$dbname = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // $dbname is now "example"
```

Comment: wouldn't this output as `Array`;

Comment: @SagarGuhe No it outputs "example." See here: https://3v4l.org/GjF8H

Comment: oh so sorry I read it like `echo pathinfo($filename);` :P

Comment: Sidenote: That should look more like `$db_name = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

echo $db_name;` - OP might not know what to do with that ;-) or `echo $db_name = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);` - That would now assign it to the table name they want to create.

Comment: @Fred-ii- whew, you'd hope even a beginner would know how to take an `echo` statement and assign to a variable? ha, maybe not. updated the answer.

Comment: @jszobody Yeah I know - *sigh*.

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = "example.csv";
//Find the position of the last occurrence of "."

$point_pos = strrpos($filename,".");

//the second argument of substr is the length of the substring
$target = substr($filename, 0, $point_pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `basename()` function:

```
<?php

// your file
$file = 'example.csv';

$info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);

echo $file_name; // outputs 'example'

?>
```